# How do I programmatically animate a .obj model?

Tags: c++, 3d

I am developing on Qt, I have tried translate and rotate an .obj model.

I would like to know is there any possibility to do programmatically animate in Qt.

Comment: This is pretty broad, and it's unclear what you've tried already. I edited your question to remove the request for libraries to do this. Requesting libraries is not a question that's on topic here.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do animations, .obj is the wrong format for you. But, never-the-less:

You can do that with mesh-keyframing, or Skeletal animation. Skeletal animation is the typical, newer, choice. But mesh-keyframing still has it's place, and is easy to implement.

**Mesh-Keyframing**: Is when you have a whole bunch of meshes that represent a model doing certain thing's, when strung together. So, doing it with OBJ models, you might have something like:

```
Person_Standing.obj
Person_Crouching.obj
Person_LayingDown.obj
...
```

Where each model has all the same data, just different places for the vertices. You then loop through, blending between two model's, and you have a smooth animation! Though, typically, people use **`.md2`** files for that. There is plenty of documentation on it.

**Skeletal Animation**: Is when you have a hierarchy much like a skeleton in the human world, your hand's connected to your arm, which is connected to your torso, which is also connected to by your head, other arm, and leg's. You then "bind" the vertices of the mesh to their respective bone, and work out a system in which moving the bone moves the vertices bound to it. Collada files are typically used for this (**`.dae`** I believe.)

Here's a couple use-full references for you:

- [Flipcode document on Skeletal Animation](http://www.flipcode.com/documents/charfaq.html#Q2)
- [A website containing many tutorial's on more than just animation](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/). And it uses a commonly used library for it's animation!

**Edit:** Some source code for you to reference.

- [An OpenGL Flight Simulator](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/flightsimulator/)
- [SpaceSimulator.net](http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php?title=3d_Engine_Programming_Tutorials)

Comment: thanks for your reply there are a lot of useful stuff i ignored , my task is very simple but i dont know how , i want to combine a coaxial rotation along with a
 translational movement of an .obj aircraft to make a simple simulation of an approach. will it be possible on skeletal animation ?

Comment: Oh, that's multiplying multiple matrices, if I understand you correctly. Skeletal animation wouldn't help with that, no. Skeletal animation is for deforming the mesh, not transforming the model. Tutorial 11 of the second link, "Concatenating transformations", should be what your looking for.

Comment: thats right , in the tutorial its simple cause they are using a simple object , what am looking for is how am gonna do whats inside the tutorial with an .obj model. thanks

Comment: You have already loaded the .obj file, right?

Comment: yes i did so whats next ?

Comment: That tutorial explains it. Your going to want to look at the theory behind it, not the actual code. But, the idea of `RotationMatrix * LocationMatrix`, applied to a simple model, is exactly the same when applied to a complex object. That's why the simple model is used, so the readers aren't worrying about the complex model.

Comment: thanks mate i'll give it a try i hope i'll figure it out

Comment: I hope you do to. I'll be happy to help in any way I can, if you have any more questions.